# iCloud drive conversion taking forever

Tags: icloud, macos

After solving unrelated problems, my 10.10 machine finally logged into iCloud properly. Most everything connected immediately, *except* iCloud Drive. For this I had to click the button to upgrade, which I did.

And it's been spinning ever since. That's about an hour and counting. Considering I had exactly one document in iCloud, and it was maybe 50 kB, I don't think this is working.

Any advice?

Comment: Please rephrase your question as you've added a lot irrelevant information as you stated yourself. Please remove it to make the question more clear.

Comment: I'm probably asking the obvious, but have you restarted your computer?

Comment: No, I was afraid it was mid process. But in retrospect, that's dumb. Here goes...